# How do I set up a Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() that actually works?

Tags: android, timer

I am using Eclipse for Android. I am trying to make a simple repeating Timer that has a short delay.
It will start after a TextView timerTV is clicked. This code is in the onCreate method:

```
    timerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTV);
    timerTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              Timer gameTimer = new Timer();
              TimerTask doThis;

              int delay = 5000;   // delay for 5 sec.
              int period = 1000;  // repeat every sec.
              doThis = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "timer is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              };
              gameTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doThis, delay, period);
```

Everytime I try to run it, a "Class File Editor" pops up with the error:
"Source not found"
The JAR file C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar has no source attachment.
You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:
[Attach Source...]
When I click this, Eclipse asks me to select the location folder containing 'android.jar'
I tried to do this, but cannot navigate all the way to the folder it is located in anyway.

I presume the issue is in my code somewhere.
I have been searching for hours, even copied and pasted code many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an actual Timer (java.util.Timer) in conjunction with runOnUiThread() is one way to solve this issue, and below is an example of how to implement it.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

private Timer myTimer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}

private void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               

    //Do something to the UI thread here

    }
};
}
```

SOURCE: http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12

Comment: There's good reasons not to capitalize any methods other than constructors and any variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Project -> Clean then right click your project and find Fix Project Properties.  Check your Build Path.  It could be any one of these things.  Restart eclipse, make sure your Android Manifest is targeting the correct API, 8 I assume?

Comment: I tried these, to no avail, but found a solution here: http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12